# TDD dummy repository storage

Tags: asp.net, tdd

What is best practice to storage dummy data wich will be pased to unit of work class ? I was thinking i can store this data to dictionary but i have quite large amount of linq queries, so it is ok to storage this data to some kind of lightweight sql database? I am new in TDD and maybe missing something important

Comment: You really want to avoid writing a unit test that has a dependency on something else (a database in this case). You *can* do that, but if you can avoid it and just store it in a dictionary, you should. It makes the test far more portable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, you could consider using something like [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/).
One thing to consider is that if you do use a dictionary of list in your test repository, there are cases where using linq against an in-memory structure returns different results to when querying a database.